# JOLT Spec for DataFrame input (NiFi JoltTransformJson)

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

Could you please help me writing JOLT spec for the following?

Input JSON:

```json
{
  "a": "1",
  "b": "2",
  "c": "3",
  "d": "4"
}
```

I need to get output:

```json
{
  "columns": ["a","b","c","d"],
  "data": [[1,2,3,4]]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **shift** transformation below :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "columns",
        "@": "data[0]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

If the elements of the data array must strictly be of type integer, then a **modify-overwrite-beta**  transformation needed too, such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=toInteger"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "columns",
        "@": "data[0]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: yes, thanks a lot